# What are the recipes in the Secret Lab?

Tags: speed-warp

The lab notes give you hints on how to make potions. What are the actual recipes?
Here are the notes:

- For **health**, split MMX in two to find your quantities. Chlorine will give you your ingredients, but remember to keep it sweet.
- For **strength**, stand in front of a mirror while making a health potion.
- **Regeneration** is more difficult to accomplish. Gold must be combined in equal part with a hard substance in a multiple of Calcium, then the solution should be brought to the boil. While simmering, add a tenth of health potion ingredients. Once the flask is cool again you should have your potion.
- **Fire** is initially the same as a regeneration potion, but only add half of the initial ingredients. While simmering, instead of a health tonic, sprinkle an equal amount of powder as gold into the mixture.

Comment: Someone asked a question about my game, I feel like I've made it!

Comment: Making a game so people ask questions so you can answer... I'll report you for trying to get easy rep.

Comment: People will do anything for meaningless internet points, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how to solve the riddle:

MMX is roman numerals. Take that number, and 'split' it (not divide). You should have two numbers. The chemical symbol for Chlorine gives you two letters that denote the ingredients.

Standing in front of a mirror reverses things.

What element at your disposal best represents Gold? What element is the hardest? What is the atomic number of Calcium?

What element at your disposal best represents powder?

And for the lazy, here's the actual quantities:

> * Health: 20 candies, 10 lollipops
>  * Strength: 10 candies, 20 lollipops
>  * Regen: 20 Coins, 20 Gobstoppers, and 2 candies and a lollipop added *while boiling*
>  * Fire: 10 Coins, 10 Gobstoppers, and 10 dust added while boiling

Comment: Could you provide source? ;P

Comment: @HenryHey Source is I'm the developer. Also, if you use the browser dev tools to view the source, the recipes are right there in `lab.js` in the comments.

Comment: Isn't M the roman numeral for 1000? How do you get 20 and 10 from MM and X?

Comment: @murgatroid99 2010 split in two is 20 and 10 :-)

Comment: @fredley I had trouble with this riddle: MMX is 2010, so I tried dividing by 2, making 1050 of each. Nope. Then I came here and learned that I should split instead of divide, so I tried splitting MMX in two. I got M-half_M and 1X. Makes no sense. Maybe if I cut horizontally… Nope. Oh, maybe it should not be an equal split! Let me try using MM = 2000 and X = 10. Nope. Maybe M = 1000 and MX = 1010… Nope. Then I gave up and read the comments to this answer. Oh, I must split after the conversion… No way to find that out! I'd suggest you s/MMX/2010/ in the game description, preventing red herrings.

Comment: @DenilsonSá 2010/2 = 1005...not 1050...not that it would have mattered...

Answer (score 1):

There is fifth recipe, a secret one in the source-code.

> It involves mixing a certain amount of all 5 basic ingredients.

> The secret recipe involves mixing 10 of each of the 5 basic ingredients.

The recipe...

> Makes everything explode, so maybe it's not such a good idea...