# Is dust used for anything besides ingots?

Tags: speed-warp

I've just unlocked the Workshop and see that dust can be combined into ingots.  I am wondering if I should just make all my dust into ingots or if I will need it later on for other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need dust for something else.

> One of the recipes in the secret lab uses dust:
>  [What are the recipes in the Secret Lab?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133223/what-are-the-recipes-in-the-secret-lab)